# How can I detect whether the process is 32 bit or 64 bit in a classic ASP app?

Tags: asp-classic, 32bit-64bit

In .NET 4.5, I can call `Environment.Is64BitProcess` to detect whether a process is running in 32 bit or 64 bit. How can I achieve the same in a Classic ASP application?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the .NET framework from classic asp.

```
Dim objUnicode
Set objUnicode = CreateObject("System.Text.UnicodeEncoding")
```

I'm not sure though what `Environment.Is64BitProcess` will return when its called from a classic asp process, but it might be worth a try!

Comment: System.Environment is a static class so I can't instantiate it using `CreateObject`.